# WordPress Custom Shortcode Conflicting with Media Library

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, actions

I have written a small function that displays a Custom Post Type called Testimonials (in my case) using a shortcode.

The Shortcode runs properly. But I noticed 1 major problem with that.

My WordPress Media library doesn't show up/loads once the Shortcode function is called.

As soon as I remove the Shortcode Function it works.

I tried WP_DEBUG to see if there is an error but it does not show anything.

Also, checked php_error log, apache_error log, there is nothing that can help me.

I then went to Site Health option and there I see

> "The REST API did not behave correctly" "The REST API did not process
>   the context query parameter correctly"

Here is the custom shortcode function -

```
<!-- Shortcode display testimonials-->
<?php

function display_testimonials()
{
    ?><div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'post_status' => 'published',

    );
    $testimonials = new WP_Query($args);

    if($testimonials->have_posts()):while($testimonials->have_posts()):$testimonials->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="item testimonial_box">
    <div class="testimonial_1box">
        <span class="testimonial_stars"><?php $stars = get_field('stars'); echo $stars;?></span>

        <span class="testimonial_content"><?php the_content();?></span>
        <h4 class="testimonial_title"><?php the_title();?></h4>

    </div>

        <div class="testimonial_2box">
            <figure class="figure_testimonial_image">
                <img class="testimonial_image" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display Lavede</p>

<?php endif;?>


</div>
<?php

wp_reset_postdata();


}

function testimonial_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode('TestimonialITW', 'display_testimonials');
}

add_action('init', 'testimonial_shortcode');
```

Comment: Shortcodes should always *return* the output and not echo it.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean that instead of echo $stars; I should replace it with a return keyword? i.e return $stars? 

I did that but then the rest of the code stops working. And also the library not loading problem still exists. Here - https://snipboard.io/uLdGBE.jpg

I apologize for sounding silly but I am just getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming you put the code in the theme `functions.php` file, and if so, then there should be no *direct output* echoed in that file:

- Good:

  ```php
  <?php // Assume this is wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php
  function some_func() {
      echo 'This is a good output; it\'s not a direct output coming from the file.';
      echo 'The output is only displayed when you call the function - some_func().';
  }
  ```
- Bad:

  ```php
  <!-- This is a HTML comment and it's a sample direct output. -->
  <?php // Assume this is wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php
  function some_func() {
      echo 'This is a good output; it\'s not a direct output coming from the file.';
      echo 'The output is only displayed when you call the function - some_func().';
  }
  ```

Secondly, the Site Health performs a test to check if the REST API is accessible (or working good) and if it's not, which could be because of invalid response, then you'd see the error "*The REST API did not behave correctly*". And that's most likely what's happening in your case because you got that `<!-- Shortcode display testimonials-->` at the top of the file (i.e. your `functions.php` file). So remove that comment and the error should be gone.

Apart from that, another issue in your code is that you need to make sure your shortcode is *returning the output* and not echoing it. If you echo it, then the output would be displayed at the wrong place (i.e. not where you put the `[TestimonialITW]` in the post content) and when you update a post having the shortcode, you'd likely see an error that says "*Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response.*" — because the response contains the output from your shortcode (e.g. HTML tags like the `<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">`).

But if you need to echo it, you can use [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2832010):

```php
function testimonial_shortcode()
{
    ob_start();             // turn on output buffering
    display_testimonials(); // put the output to the buffer
    return ob_get_clean();  // capture and return the buffer
}
add_shortcode( 'TestimonialITW', 'testimonial_shortcode' );
```

And that would replace the following:

```php
function testimonial_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode('TestimonialITW', 'display_testimonials');
}

add_action('init', 'testimonial_shortcode');
```

Additionally, unless you have registered a custom post status named `published`, that `'post_status' => 'published'` should be `'post_status' => 'publish'`.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the clear explanation and writing a detailed solution for me. It worked. I learned 2 important things from the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome! And remember, the "direct output" could also be a space, so make sure it doesn't exist at the top (before the opening `<?php` tag) or at the end of the file (hint: don't close the PHP tag - `<?php /* code here..... */` - no `?>` at the end). :) Also for simple shortcodes, you could use string concatenation: `$output = ''; $output .= 'append output'; return $output` - but that's of course a simplified example.

Comment: This will surely help me in improving the overall code. I am planning to create a FREE plugin out of this that might be helpful for others. So yeah it's a long process. Have to learn so many things before actually having a plugin of my own in the WordPress repository. Individuals like you will always help I am certain of that.

Comment: Yep, you can always post another question, but remember to be [on-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).. :) Anyway, good luck with that plugin!